# Adding attributes to jButton [JAVA]

Tags: java, object, jbutton

Lets say i have an array of 100 employees. Each employee in the array, is an instance of the class Employee, that have many attributes, such as name, direction, salary, etc.

I want to display, 1 button for each employee in the array, and when you click one, you get the information of that employee.

What i don't know, is how can i link a button to an specific employee. I Was thinking on, somehow, attaching an Integer variable to the button, so i know which employee is related to that specific button, but, i don't really know how to do that.

Anyone cares to give me some advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `setName(employeeId)` method for JButton to set Employee's id or use `putClientProperty("id", employeeId)`, when you get a callback at button's listener you could get the name or your property.

Comment: Could you explain a little more about the getClientProperty? Google gives me nothing besides the Java documentation, and whenever i try to use the getClientProperty("someId"); or this.getClientProperty("someId"); function inside an actionPerformed, i get a non existing method error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `putClientProperty` and `getClientProperty` to attach any object to a `JComponent`.

Answer (score 1):

If you get "this" inside listener you get a reference to listener's object. You should use getSource() method, like:

```
JButton j = new JButton("click here");
    j.putClientProperty("id", "employee1");

    j.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            JButton source = (JButton)ae.getSource();
            String id = (String) source.getClientProperty("id");
            System.out.print(id);
        }
    });
```

Will print - employee1.